# Determine the convergence of the series

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Is the series $$\sum_{i=1}^\infty\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}{\log^2 n}}$$ convergent or divergent? I am using the Cauchy Condensation Test, but still stuck to prove it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT:**

For any $0<\alpha$

$$\log(n)\le \frac{n^\alpha}{\alpha}$$

Comment: OK thank you. I can apply this formular by $\alpha = 1/4$. Then I can show that the series is divergent.

Comment: Yes!  We done. And you're welcome.  My pleasure.

Answer (score 1):

The $\log n$, and its sister exponent like $\log^\alpha n$, where $\alpha > 0$ and is constant can be made less than $n^\beta$ with $\beta > 0$ and can be as small as you choose, say $\beta = 0.05$ if you so like when $n$ gets large enough. This means the denominator can be made less than $n^c$ with $0 < c < 1$, and you can invoke the $p$ series with $p = 1$ and they call it the harmonic series whose convergence/divergence status is known.

Comment: Same idea as mine.  ;-))

Comment: Wish I could be in Houston to help you with stuffs, Mark.

Comment: Much appreciate your kind sentiment!

Comment: $\log(n)$ and its "sister exponent?" $\log^{\alpha} n$ are constants?

Comment: I dont understand the phrase "The $logn$ and its sister exponent are constant

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**

Can you compare to $1/n$?

Comment: I think it does not work to compare with $1/n$

Comment: @user386505 There is a version of limit comparison test that says if $\frac{a_n}{b_n} \to \infty$ and $b_n$ diverges then $a_n$ diverges as well.

Comment: @RabMakh: Your comment doesn't seem to apply here. We have a series and a direct comparison test suffices because eventually $1/n$ is less than $1/(\sqrt{n}\log(n)^2)$.

Comment: @user386505: It works. See my above comment.

Comment: @user21820: the two tests are equivalent as far as I know.

Comment: @RabMakh: What are you talking about? $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{k}{k^2+1} \ge \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac1{2k} = \infty$, but the ratio of terms tends to $2$ and the ratio of sums also tends to some constant, not infinity.

Comment: @user21820: And we know that when the ratio of the terms tend to a number that is not $0$, the series both diverges or converge.
http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LimitComparisonTest.html

(which in this case, both diverge)

Comment: @RabMakh: I know those facts and their proofs very well. What I don't know is what you are talking about, since in your first comment you wrote ratio of terms tending to infinity, which has nothing to do with the question since we are **not** talking about the terms diverging but the sum.......